# removing specific file from fileupload control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a file upload control

```
 <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ClientIDMode="Static" name="aa[]" BackColor="Azure"
                            ForeColor="Black" OnClientUploadError="uploadError" OnClientUploadStarted="abc"
                            multiple="multiple" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server" ID="AsyncFileUpload1"
                            Width="400px" CompleteBackColor="White" UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
```

I want to remove specific file from fileupload control.

lets say I want to remove second file, so I want to achieve something like this

```
 fileupload1.files[1].remove()
```

Is it possible in fileupload control?

I want to achieve it in javascript

Answer (score 0):

using JavaScript its possible if you use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/FileReader) then you have add normal file input change event listener then loop through each file from change event, filter for desired validation,push valid files into separate array
use FileReader API to read files locally submit valid, processed files to server like this code example:

```
var validatedFiles = [];
$("#fileToUpload").on("change", function (event) {
  var files = event.originalEvent.target.files;
  files.forEach(function (file) {
    if (file.name.matches(/something.txt/)) {
      validatedFiles.push(file); // Simplest case
    } else { 
      /* do something else */
    }
  });
});

validatedFiles.forEach(function (file) {
    if (file.name.matches(/something.txt/)) { // You could also do more complicated validation after processing the file client side
      var reader = new FileReader();
      // Setup listener
      reader.onload = (function (processedFile) {
        return function (e) {
          var fileData = { name : processedFile.name, fileData : e.target.result };

          // Submit individual file to server
          $.post("/your/url/here", fileData);

          // or add to list to submit as group later
          validatedFiles.push(fileData);
        };
      })(file);

      // Process file
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else { 
      /* still do something else */
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps